# Autostart Firefox on CentOS 6 kiosk system with Gnome Display Manager + Openmotif Window Manager

Tags: centos, xorg, gnome

I am in process of creating kiosk system on CentOS 6.9 minimal install with Gnome Display Manager (gdm) and Openmotif Window Manager (mwm) and Firefox web browser.

I have connected gdm to mwm by installing xorg-x11-xinit-session packet and creating ~/.Xclients file with single line

```
/usr/bin/mwm
```

like described in question https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1339013

Now after I enter my credentials on Gnome Display Manager - Openmotif Window Manager launches

Now my task is to start Firefox (preferably in full screen) when Openmotif Window Manager launches

I can successfully start Firefox if I pin it to Openmotif right click menu by changing Openmotif configuration file /etc/X11/mwm/system.mwmrc but I need that Firefox will start automatically

If I change ~/.Xclients file like this

```
/usr/bin/mwm
firefox
```

or like this

```
/usr/bin/mwm
/usr/bin/firefox
```

then Openmotif start up successfully, but firefox do not

How can I start Firefox (prerably in Full screen mode) after Openmotif Window Manager launches?

Comment: `~/.Xcients` looks like it should be `~/.Xclients` - a typo here only or in the real world, too?

Comment: A typo only here

Comment: then my Answer should work?! Please try and let me know so I can adapt it if necessary.

Comment: I am glad. Please mark the answer as working so that people know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mwm` does not exit, and until it does, the `firefox` command will not be started.  So, start `mwm` in the background, like this:

```
/usr/bin/mwm &
/usr/bin/firefox
```

That way, once firefox exits, your session may exit.  If you do not like that you can do

```
/usr/bin/mwm &
PID="$!"
/usr/bin/firefox &
wait $PID
```

Oh, and you mistyped `~/.Xclients`, but probably only in this question.

Alternatively, if for some reason in the first variant `mwm` does not exit when `firefox` does, but you want it to, you can do

```
/usr/bin/mwm &
WMPID="$!"
/usr/bin/firefox
kill -HUP $WMPID
```

Comment: You could also add a `sleep 1` or `sleep 2` before the `firefox` line to give the window manager a second or two to start up before starting `firefox`. This may or may not be useful in your setup, depending on your hardware/speed and desired use case.